# Cannot open file with Ruby Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby `2.6.6` I am not able to open a file the regular way.

```
2.6.6 :006 > File.open "https://www.pocket-rocket.io/robots.txt"
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7: from /Users/martinbraun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        6: from /Users/martinbraun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        5: from /Users/martinbraun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from (irb):6
        3: from (irb):6:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        2: from (irb):6:in `open'
        1: from (irb):6:in `initialize'
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.pocket-rocket.io/robots.txt)
```

The file exists and I am able to browse to it using my browser.
But I keep getting this error.

I tried:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

no success.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it a possible problem with this Ruby version?
I could not find any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.open` expects files to be on the disk, it doesn't work with remote files.

Instead you could do use `Net::HTTP.get`, which will return a string.

```
 url = URI('https://www.pocket-rocket.io/robots.txt')
 Net::HTTP.get(url) # => "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /wp-admin/\nAllow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php\n"
```